# WINXP - Synergy log - Debug

Tags: ubuntu, synergy

I'm trying to set up Synergy between Windows XP (server) and Ubuntu Linux.

When I try and move my curser over the edge of the screen, the following appears in the logs:

```
2011-04-13T20:21:23 DEBUG2: find neighbor on right of "WINXP"
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,611
2011-04-13T20:21:23 DEBUG2: ignored "LinuxPC" on right of "WINXP"
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,640
2011-04-13T20:21:23 DEBUG2: no neighbor on right of "LinuxPC"
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,626
2011-04-13T20:21:23 DEBUG1: try to leave "WINXP" on right
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,808
2011-04-13T20:21:23 DEBUG1: no neighbor right
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,814
2011-04-13T20:21:23 DEBUG2: find neighbor on right of "WINXP"
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,611
2011-04-13T20:21:23 DEBUG2: ignored "LinuxPC" on right of "WINXP"
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,640
2011-04-13T20:21:23 DEBUG2: no neighbor on right of "LinuxPC"
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,626
2011-04-13T20:21:23 DEBUG1: try to leave "WINXP" on right
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,808
2011-04-13T20:21:23 DEBUG1: no neighbor right
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,814
```

What do these numbers mean - `814 / 808 / 626 / 640 / 611`? Is there a website with all the Synergy error codes?

Is there a "load & go" version for Ubuntu ? I have quicksynergy. I can't find the logs as yet. The keyboard and mouse are very slow and hard to control.

Comment: Please format the log output appropriately, it's nearly impossible to read when it's all on the same line!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the numbers are the line numbers within the source file specified.

QuickSynergy just calls the 'standard' synergy command line tools.

For Ubuntu you should be able to test synergy with:

```
$ synergyc -f -d 2 <ip of server>
```

That should start synergy client, connect to the server, and give you debugging information to stderr.  You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to terminate the client.

To just start it in the background you can use:

```
$ synergyc <ip of server>
```

Comment: Cool - Using this - $ synergyc <ip of server> - on my Ubuntu machine, worked first time :)

Comment: Is there a way i can have it load up automatically at start-up (before i log in ? )

Comment: If you need to log in to Ubuntu then you would need to add it to your /etc/gdm/Init/Default file so it runs when gdm does.  You also need to add it to your startup programs in Ubuntu so it runs when your session starts.